# Shortest code to check if all int array elements are equal to a specific number?

Tags: c, arrays, arduino, equality

What's the shortest way I can do an if..else statement to check if all int array elements are equal to certain numbers? For example in pseudocode:

```
if (allElementsOfIntArray == -1)
   //do something
else if (allElementsOfIntArray == 1)
  //do something else
```

I have another variable that is `const int arraySize`

My Arduino code is getting really messy at this point so I'm just trying to find the shortest way to implement this so it doesn't look like a mess to others that have to read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool all_are(int* i_begin, std::size_t sz, int x)
{
    const int* i_end = i_begin + sz;
    for(; i_begin != i_end; ++i_begin)
        if(*i_begin != x) return false;

    return true;
}
```

```
if (all_are(my_array, arraySize, -1))
   //do something
else if (all_are(my_array, arraySize, 1))
  //do something else
```

Comment: Missing an `i_end` in the `for` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Check first if all entries are the same and then `switch()`:

```
for (int i=1; i<arraysize; i++)
   if (theArray[0] != theArray[i]) return "no way";

/*** All array elements are the same, so we can evaluate any element ***/

switch (theArray[0]) 
{
   case 0:
        return "All are zero";
   case 1:
        return "All are one";
   default:
        return "All elements are the same";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way that pops into mind (assuming the array is unsorted) is to just iterate through it and checking each element. You can do this a few ways. Use a normal `for` loop or try a `for each`.

Answer (score 0):

Each element in array is independent to others. So you must use *for* to check all of it to make sure.